# Finite dimensional separable algebra is étale

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, commutative-algebra, extension-field, tensor-products

Say a $\Bbbk$-algebra is *separable* if $L\otimes _\Bbbk A$ is reduced for every extension $L/\Bbbk$. Say it's *étale* if there's an extension $L/\Bbbk$ such that $L\otimes_\Bbbk A\cong \prod_1^nL$.

Here's a two line proof that f.d. separable implies étale:

> Let $\overline \Bbbk$ be an algebraic closure of $\Bbbk$. Then
>   $\overline \Bbbk \otimes _\Bbbk A$ is a reduced f.d.
>   $\overline\Bbbk$-algebra. Being finite dimensional reduced implies
>   being Artin so Artin-Wedderburn gives a desired isomorphism.

Is it really necessary to use $\overline \Bbbk$? Why not just take some $L/\Bbbk$ such that $L\otimes _\Bbbk A$ is reduced? In other words, what is the problem with the following:

> Let $L/\Bbbk$ be an extension such that
>    $L \otimes _\Bbbk A$ is reduced. This is a reduced f.d. (?) algebra, so Artin-Wedderburn and done.

**Update:** Thanks to user26857's comments I understand I've been careless. It seems then that for algebraically closed fields the only possible decomposition can be by copies of the field itself. Why is this?

Comment: What is "f.d"??

Comment: @user26857 finite dimensional

Comment: I supposed so, but I wanted to be sure. Thanks.

Comment: @user26857 sorry for being unclear!

Comment: AFAIK a reduced f.d. algebra over a field $k$ is a direct product of fields. Moreover, these fields are finite extensions of $k$. But you need a little more: a direct product of *copies* of the same field, and here enters the scene the algebraic closure.

Comment: @user26857 Thanks! I edited my question a little. Could you explain how the algebraic closure resolves everything?

Comment: An algebraic closed field doesn't have finite field extensions (other than itself).

Comment: @user26857 oh, right. Well if you'd like to post this as an answer I'll gladly accept.